# Error in using if condition in Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have written the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
main()
{
    echo 'Checking if process is running...'
    if [ [ps -ef|grep "Djava.security.auth.login.config"|grep -v grep|wc -l] != 0 ]; then
            echo "startEventProcessorScript is not running"
            nohup /apps/fasigw/test/bin/startEventProcessor &
    fi

    echo '******************************************************************'
    echo ' Script started successfully '
    echo '******************************************************************'
}
main $*
```

When I am executing the above script, I get the following error message:

```
Checking if process is running...
main[3]: test: ] missing
wc: illegal option -- ]
usage: wc [-c|-m] [-lw] [name ...]
```

I am unable to fix this issue. **startEventProcessor** is a script that is in path /apps/fasigw/test/bin. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the output of a command within your `if` statement, you should use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), i.e. use `$(...)` instead of `[..]`.

```
if [ $(ps -ef|grep "Djava.security.auth.login.config"|grep -v grep|wc -l) != 0 ]
```

Note that this can be simplified to:

```
if [ $(pgrep -cf "Djava.security.auth.login.config") != 0 ]
```

or :

```
if ps -ef | grep -q "[D]java.security.auth.login.config"; then
```

(the brackets in the `"[D]java..."` is a trick often used to ensure that the grep command does not match its own process).